# Add columns to an Access (Jet) table from .NET

Tags: .net, database, ms-access, jet

Our app (already deployed) is using an Access/Jet database. The upcoming version of our software requires some additional columns in one of the tables. I need to first check if these columns exist, and then add them if they don't.

Can someone provide a quick code sample, link, or nudge in the right direction?

(I'm using c#, but a VB.NET sample would be fine, too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head, but something like:

```
Dim conn as New AdoConnection(someConnStr)
Dim cmd as New AdoCommand
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE X ADD COLUMN y COLUMNTYPE"
cmd.ComandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the table for the field you expect and handle the error if the field is not there.

Too add the column, just feed the database an [alter table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177883.aspx) SQL statement.