# Database column creation through ADOX.Table

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, adox

I'm trying to create columns in an existing `access database`. The `database` has already been created, it contains the empty table named "table1", but it does not contain any `columns`, now I want to add a column into it. But it produces some error.

> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are
>   in conflict with one another.

```
Imports ADOX
Imports ADOX.DataTypeEnum
Imports ADOX.KeyTypeEnum
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

 Dim database_location As String = Application.UserAppDataPath

    Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
           insert_columns("DB3", "table1", "Key", adInteger, True, True)
        End Sub

    Function insert_columns(ByRef Database_file_name As String, ByRef table_name As String, ByRef column_name As String, ByRef data_type As ADOX.DataTypeEnum, Optional ByRef primary_key As Boolean = False, Optional ByRef auto_increment As Boolean = False)

            Dim DB_file_name As String = "\" & Database_file_name & ".mdb"
            Dim catDB As ADOX.Catalog
            Dim tblNew As ADOX.Table
            ' Dim catstring As String

            'Try
            catDB = New ADOX.Catalog
            ' Open the catalog.
            catDB.ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & database_location & DB_file_name

            tblNew = New ADOX.Table
            ' Create a new Table object.
            With tblNew
                .Name = table_name
                .ParentCatalog = catDB
                ' Create fields and append them to the
                ' Columns collection of the new Table object.

                With .Columns
                    .Append(column_name, data_type)

                    If auto_increment = True Then
                        .Item(column_name).Properties("AutoIncrement").Value = True
                    End If

                    If primary_key = True Then
                        tblNew.Keys.Append("PrimaryKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, column_name)
                    End If

                End With

            End With

            ' Add the new Table to the Tables collection of the database.
            catDB.Tables.Append(tblNew)

            'clean up
            catDB = Nothing
            tblNew = Nothing

            Return True

            'Catch ex As Exception
            '    error_entry("Column creation error. Database name: " & DB_file_name & " Column Name: " & column_name & vbNewLine & ex.Message)
            '    Return False
            'End Try
        End Function
```

Comment: At least one thing that is wrong is that it creates a new table instead of trying to modify an existing table.  Use the Tables collection to find the existing table back.

Answer (score -1):

Argh, didn't read properly that you are using adox. I'll leave the answer just in case.

I used ACE but it should be the same:

```
  Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand() 'Creates table and columns in it
        cmd.Connection = <your connection>
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [" & <table_name> & "]([<column_name>] <COLUMN TYPE>, ...repeat)" ' so it looks like "CREATE TABLE [NewTable]([Column1] TEXT, [Columnnnnz2] INTEGER)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
```

If you want to add columns independently then [Add columns to an Access (Jet) table from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251560/add-columns-to-an-access-jet-table-from-net)